# Java 8 Stream dynamic filter field of a class

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a class with properties that have their getter and setter each.

I load a list of this class with values from a DB, and I need to create a function that can make a filter over this stream calling different method from the class.

Example:

```
listActionfilter.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getAccion().toUpperCase().trim().contains(accion))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I need to do is this:

```
function xxx('**methodtosearch**', '**valuetosearch**') {
    listActionfilter.stream()
        .filter(u -> u.('**methodtosearch**')
            .toUpperCase().trim().contains('**valuetosearch**'))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your function could have the following signature (assuming the object is an `ListAction` object...

```
public List<ListAction> function(Predicate<ListAction> predicate) {
    return listActionfilter.stream()
                           .filter(predicate)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And call it the following way

```
function(u -> u.getAccion().toUpperCase().trim().contains(accion));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all your target methods returns String, you can use this :

```
public List<Action> xxx(Function<Action, String> methodSelector, String valueToMatch) {
return listActionfilter.stream()
                       .filter(t -> methodSelector.apply(t).toUpperCase().trim(). contains(valueToMatch))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can invoke the method like this :

```
List<Action> list1 = xxx(Accion::method1, "value1")
List<Action> list2 = xxx(Accion::method2, "value2")
```

Comment: Due to the `map()`, this would actually return a `List<String>`. Also you could use just `map(methodSelector)` there since you already have the right `Function`.

Comment: Correct, I should have applied map here. Edited the answer.